# Botones prev/next plugin FancyBox no funcionan

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

alguien ha usado alguna vez el plugin Fancybox. Tengo problemas con los botones para ir a la imagen previa y a la siguiente, no me funcionan.

Hay que activarlo de alguna manera por jquery? no he encontrado nada en las instrucciones del propio plugin.
Yo creo que está todo bien maquetado.

```
          <ul class="thumb__list">
        <li class="thumb__item">
          <a data-fancybox="images" data-caption="Sala de espera de la Clínica" href="images/sala_de_espera.jpg" class="thumb__veil popup">
            <div class="thumb__content">
              <svg>
                <use xlink:href="icons.svg#icon-resize-full-screen"></use>
              </svg>
              <p>Sala de espera</p>
            </div>
            <img src="images/thumb_sala_de_espera.jpg">
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="thumb__item">
          <a data-fancybox="images" data-caption="Recepción" href="images/recepcion.jpg" class="thumb__veil popup">
            <div class="thumb__content">
              <svg>
                <use xlink:href="icons.svg#icon-resize-full-screen"></use>
              </svg>
              <p>Recepción</p>
            </div>
            <img src="images/thumb_recepcion.jpg">
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="thumb__item">
          <a data-fancybox="images" data-caption="Acceso a la consulta" href="images/acceso_consulta.jpg" class="thumb__veil popup">
            <div class="thumb__content">
              <svg>
                <use xlink:href="icons.svg#icon-resize-full-screen"></use>
              </svg>
              <p>Acceso a la consulta</p>
            </div>
            <img src="images/thumb_acceso_consulta.jpg" class="thumb__veil">
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="thumb__item">
          <a data-fancybox="images" data-caption="Consulta principal" href="images/consulta_2.jpg" class="thumb__veil popup">
            <div class="thumb__content">
              <svg>
                <use xlink:href="icons.svg#icon-resize-full-screen"></use>
              </svg>
              <p>Consulta principal</p>
            </div>
            <img src="images/thumb_consulta_2.jpg" class="thumb__veil">
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="thumb__item">
          <a data-fancybox="images" data-caption="Consulta" href="images/consulta.jpg" class="thumb__veil popup">
            <div class="thumb__content">
              <svg>
                <use xlink:href="icons.svg#icon-resize-full-screen"></use>
              </svg>
              <p>Consulta</p>
            </div>
            <img src="images/thumb_consulta.jpg" class="thumb__veil">
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="thumb__item">
          <a data-fancybox="images" data-caption="Equipo de la Clínica" href="images/equipo.jpg" class="thumb__veil popup">
            <div class="thumb__content">
              <svg>
                <use xlink:href="icons.svg#icon-resize-full-screen"></use>
              </svg>
              <p>Equipo de la Clínica</p>
            </div>
            <img src="images/thumb_equipo.jpg" class="thumb__veil">
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="thumb__item">
          <a data-fancybox="images" data-caption="Instrumental de la Clínica" href="images/instrumental.jpg" class="thumb__veil popup">
            <div class="thumb__content">
              <svg>
                <use xlink:href="icons.svg#icon-resize-full-screen"></use>
              </svg>
              <p>Instrumental de la Clínica</p>
            </div>
            <img src="images/thumb_instrumental.jpg" class="thumb__veil">
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="thumb__item">
          <a data-fancybox="images" data-caption="Octopantomografía" href="images/octopantomografia.jpg" class="thumb__veil popup">
            <div class="thumb__content">
              <svg>
                <use xlink:href="icons.svg#icon-resize-full-screen"></use>
              </svg>
              <p>Octopantomografía</p>
            </div>
            <img src="images/thumb_octopantomografia.jpg" class="thumb__veil">
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="thumb__item">
          <a data-fancybox="images" data-caption="Radiografía digitalizada" href="images/radiografia_digitalizada.jpg" class="thumb__veil popup">
            <div class="thumb__content">
              <svg>
                <use xlink:href="icons.svg#icon-resize-full-screen"></use>
              </svg>
              <p>Radiografía digitalizada</p>
            </div>
            <img src="images/thumb_radiografia_digitalizada.jpg" class="thumb__veil">
          </a>
        </li> 
      </ul>
```

Comment: Deberias aportarnos más información. Has importado el plugin desde algún js o desde el propio html? Has comprobado `Ctrl + mayus + i` si la consola del navegador muestra errores al pulsar o antes? Cuales son? Si tuviese mas reputación lo pondría como comentario y no como respuesta... De todas formas por si no lo has leido, yo miraría bien la documentación oficial [aquí](http://fancybox.net/howto). Un saludo

Comment: @Oskar he importado el plugin desde el js, descargado desde su pag oficial. Los botones next/prev funciona bien en móviles, menos en escritorio. La consola no lanza ningún error (si no ya lo hubiera puesto)